# loading an input file in Ruby which is a slight variation of Ruby

Tags: ruby, input, metaprogramming, dsl

Is there a way that I can load a user-defined Ruby input file into my application in a way that I can access any variables, methods, and classes defined in the input file?. An example input file might look like this:

```
def my_callback(t)
    t ** 2
end
parameter_x = "10 bytes"
parameter_y = my_callback
```

In my application, I would like to do something like the following:

```
input = load_input_file
puts input.parameter_x     # => "10 bytes"
puts input.parameter_y(2)  # => 4
```

If it isn't possible to load the input file into an object's namespace, the next best thing would be local access to the variables (as long as they aren't globally visible):

```
load_input_file
puts parameter_x     # => "10 bytes"
puts parameter_y(2)  # => 4
```

Is this possible (without manually parsing the input file)?

Comment: It doesn't seem to allow access to variables defined in the input file.

Comment: How are you calling the variables and methods, through `input.parameter_x` or `parameter_x`? After the `require`, that is.

Comment: I'm invoking it as "parameter_x". The method invocation seems to work fine, but the attempt to access the variable is causing the error "undefined local variable or method `parameter_x' for main:Object (NameError)".

Comment: does it need to be a generic ruby file, or could you have the user put everything inside a Module?

Comment: Patrick: Yes, I can access constants, but not variables.

@YenTheFirst: I could read the entire input file in as a string, enclose it inside a module. But, if possible, I'd like to avoid burdening users by requiring them to add module definition boilerplate code to all their input files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think these are your options:

#### 1. Wrap a `module` around `input.rb`:

```
module Input
  CONST = 1
  def meth
   ...
end
```

But your users will need to add: `module Input` and `end` around their code. (Not too much to ask for, is it?)

#### 2. Stringification

Per your own suggestion:
Strinigfy the `input.rb` file, wrap it with a module, and change the local variables to ivars, then ouput that to a `input_modified.rb` file:

In this case, it would be much easier if you told your users to prepend an `@` before their variable declarations.

```
require 'fileutils'
require 'tempfile'

inp = 'input.rb'
oup = 'input_modified.rb'
out = Tempfile.new('temp.txt')

File.open(inp, 'r') do |file|
  out.puts "module Input\n" + file.read.gsub("\n","\n\s") + "\nend"
end
FileUtils.mv out.path, oup
```

Comment: Upvoted and almost ready to accept this, but when I put the code I posted in the question in a module and try to load it, it says "`my_callback': wrong number of arguments (ArgumentError)". The interpreter is trying to invoke the method 'my_callback' instead of assigning it to a variable. Any idea why this is happening and/or how to work around it?

Comment: Oh, oops, sorry, I forgot to post that in my comment. It's the line that assigns my_callback to parameter_y: "parameter_y = my_callback"

Comment: Your `my_callback` needs exactly 1 an argument, but you're giving it  0, I think that's the problem. You should rename the method to `parameter_y` or have `parameter_y = my_callback SOME_VAL`

Comment: Sorry, I'm probably not communicating very clearly right now. What I meant to say is that I want "parameter_y" to be a callable object in the way "my_callback" is callable. I don't actually want to invoke my_callback in the assignment statement. This works for code not nested inside a module, e.g. "parameter_y = my_callback" at the top level scope of a Ruby script assigns a callable object to parameter_y. For some reason enclosing it in a module changes this behavior. If I can't find a better solution, for now I'm just writing "parameter_y = :my_callback" and calling it later by name.

Comment: Okay. No problem. I seriously don't know why you can't do that with models though. I thought you could, but I guess not. Hope you find a solution that works, though ;)